# How to create circle around maker when using Google maps MarkerCluster for api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am using Google maps MarkerCluster for api v3 to create cluster marker. It works well. But I want to use the circle around marker and can drag the radius of circle.

```
var markerClusterer = null;
var map = null;
var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' +
    'chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.578498, 2.457275),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];

    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl, new google.maps.Size(24, 32));
    for (var i = 0; i < macDoList.length; i++) {

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(macDoList[i].lat,
            macDoList[i].lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            icon: markerImage
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }

    markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        maxZoom: 16,
        gridSize: 100,
        styles: clusterStyles
    });


}

function clearClusters(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Anyone can help me to resolve this case?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including a sample of `macDoList` that allows your issue to be reproduced.

Comment: There is a DistanceWidget, circle with draggable radius (and center), in [this article in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun). Note that the use of the MarkerClusterer probably isn't really an issue, but you may need to handle it specially.  Do you have the functionality you want working without the MarkerClusterer?

Answer (score 1):

I create circle successfully. I'd like to share my solution for everyone. Hope it's useful for another one.

```
function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.578498, 2.457275),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];

    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl, new google.maps.Size(24, 32));
    for (var i = 0; i < macDoList.length; i++) {

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(macDoList[i].lat,
            macDoList[i].lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
        icon: markerImage
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(a) {
        var drawCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.position.lat(), this.position.lng()),
            editable:true,
            radius: 50, // metres
            fillColor: 'yellow'
        });
        drawCircle.setMap(map);            
        //circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```